# PHPUnit Command Line Tool Not working

Tags: php, windows, phpunit, command-line-interface

I run XAMPP on windows.

I've recently downloaded PHPUnit from the PEAR CLI tool.

Everything looks fine, (eclipse correctly suggests code completion so it means that it was correctly added to the include_path),**but** whenever I try and get it to work via console by typing `phpunit` (it's in the environmental PATH variable), it hangs on for a seconds or two and then closes( as if it was terminated).

I've tried `phpunit --help` also, and no success.

Also tried `phpunit --verbose`.

Has anyone else had that same problem or knows the solution?

Comment: If you navigate to the phpunit folder and then try and execute phpunit does it work?

Comment: PHPUnit instantiates all test cases before it prints out the PHPUnit version and author so it can sometimes seem like it is stalled. Try running it with a single simple test case to make sure it works. As others have said, enable all error reporting. Can you run tests within Eclipse?

Comment: @jakenoble No it doesn't...

@David I'll try that thanks. I didn't know you could do that through eclipse. I'll try that too.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Make sure your PEAR is up do date:

```
pear upgrade-all
```

Do the above until it says nothing to "upgrade-all" then reinstall PHPUnit

```
pear install --alldeps --force phpunit/PHPUnit
```

If this doesnt fix the error, make sure you have all error reporting enabled in your php.ini and check your error logs.

If this doesn't work, consider using [PHPUnit via Composer or Phar instead of PEAR](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/)

Comment: This didn't help on Debian.

Answer (score 1):

For Debian or Ubuntu, add this to your PHP ini file:

```
suhosin.executor.include.whitelist="phar"
```